# vCenter Log on as a Service Concerns

Tags: active-directory, vmware-vsphere, vmware-vcenter, service-accounts

I was installing VMWare vCenter Server 6.0 on Windows Server 2012 R2 when I came across vCenter Server Service Account feature. I can use a local system account or specify a service account on my domain. After doing some googling, I have found that a service account allows processes to be run on a machine as a user even if there isn't a user logged in. However, I don't quite understand why I would want to do this or how I could benefit. If I were to do this, would I want to create a new account to use exclusively as the service account? Is it recommended that the account have domain or local admin?

Comment: http://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-65/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.vsphere.security.doc%2FGUID-6C181D08-6650-4AD1-92D1-AAFDA3A3E38C.html